NavigationMixin redirect to same community page
I am currently trying to get a use case to work, but am not getting perfect results. I have a header LWC which has a dropdown of records, which redirects to custom summary LWC of the clicked record.  This works fine using:
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: "comm__namedPage",
    attributes: {
      name: 'Summary__c'
    },
    state: {
      tabName: pageType,
      recordId: recordId
    }
  });

The issue I am facing is, this is a header component so it is visible always, so if I am currently viewing a record's summary page and I click a different record in the header, it appears NavigationMixin doesn't do anything because I am already on the summary page.
I can accomplish it by using a regular URL redirect but this seems to refresh the whole page rather than what's just below the header like NavigationMixin.   pls help

Have you tried communicating between these components using events rather than NavigationMixin? Your custom summary component could listen for the event passed from your header, and on receiving the event refresh the data in the component.
